# In the set {1, 2, 3, ..., 2019}, we pick a, b, and c randomly without any conditions. What is the probability for abc + bc + c to be divisible by 3?

Tags: probability, number-theory

3 integers a, b, and c are randomly taken from the set {1, 2, 3, ..., 2019} without any conditions. What is the probability for abc + bc + c is divisible by 3?

Correct me if I'm wrong please.

abc + bc + c = c(ab + b + 1).
We can conclude that c has to be a multiple of 3, so we have 1/3 probability for c. a and b are any integers from the set.

AND, ab + b + 1 has to be  a multiple of 3 in the case that c is not a multiple of 3.

ab + b + 1 = b(a + 1) + 1.

b(a + 1) has to be in the form 3n - 1 for b(a + 1) + 1 to be a multiple of 3.

And this is where I get stuck. New solutions, hints, or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a solution to $b(a+1)+1=3n$ where $n$ is arbitrary, we need to have $$(b(a+1)+1) \mod 3=0$$ which means we need $(b(a+1)) \mod 3=2$. That can happen if $a\mod 3=0$ and $b\mod 3=2$ or $a\mod 3=1$ and $b\mod 3=1$.

For example $a=3$, $b=8$ has $a\mod3=0$ and $b\mod3=2$ and $8(3+1)+1=33=3\times11$, and $a=4$, $b=4$ has $a\mod3=b\mod3=1$ and $4(4+1)+1=21=3\times7$.

Since these two sets don't overlap each other, you can just add them, so $\frac292019$ of pairs of $a$ and $b$ match the criterion, in addition to the $c$s which match.

Comment: @Hayst, note that the final formula is necessarily far less simple than a mere addition or product (see my answer).

Comment: Im not too familiar with modulo arithmetic, but i can somewhat understand. But i do have a question.

Comment: I understand why (b(a+1)) mod3 = 2, but how do you conclude that a mod3 = 0 and b mod3 = 2 based on that?

Comment: @Hayst we conclude that *either* $a\equiv0\bmod3$ and $b\equiv2(\equiv-1)\bmod3$, *or* $a\equiv b\equiv1\bmod3$, by case analysis (computing $b(a+1)$ for the 9 pairs $(a\bmod3,b\bmod3)$) or, more rapidly, by saying that a product $xy$ is $\equiv2\bmod3$ iff $(x\bmod3,y\bmod3)$ is either $(2,1)$ or $(1,2)$.

Comment: "$\frac{2}{9}2019$ of pairs of $a$ and $b$" sounds like you're talking about an integral number of pairs.

Answer (score 2):

The value of $ab+b+1\bmod3$ only depends on $a\bmod3$ and $b\bmod3$. By case analysis, we find that $ab+b+1$ is a multiple of $3$ iff either $a\bmod3=b\bmod3=1$ or $a\bmod3=0$ and $b\bmod3=-1$. This happens with probability $\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{3^2}=\frac29$.

The probability for $abc + bc + c$ to be a multiple of $3$ is:
$$1-\left(1-\frac13\right)\left(1-\frac29\right)=\frac{13}{27}.$$

Comment: This answer unfortunately is incorrect. If $a\mod3=0$ and $b\mod3=2$ then $ab+b+1$ will be equal to $3n$ for some $n$. For example if a=3 and b=8, ab+b+1=33 but a mod 3 = 0 and b mod 3=2.

Comment: Yes, thank you: my "case analysis" was incomplete (I only considered the classes of 1 and 0 mod 3 and forgot the class of -1). I shall correct my answer.